# Detect object over another object as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection

let's say I have two shapes wrapped in Movieclip container. How can I detect if one shape is OVER another one?  more precisely, whether one shape is covering a part/all of the other shape?

So far I've managed to do it by comparing coordinates of both shapes, but I'm wondering if there is some built-in function or an easier way to do it.   Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DisplayObject.hitTestObject(obj:DisplayObject):Boolean

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject()

If you need finer grain hit testing and are willing to work with BitmapData objects (you can draw a DisplayObject to BitmapData using BitmapData.draw(dispObj));

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#hitTest()

Comment: exactly what i needed, thanks!  I will accept your answer in 9 minutes :) (timer)

Comment: Great glad it helps, always nice when I can answer one without doing serious research, best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple ways you could do this:

[flash.display.DisplayObject.hitTest()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29)

or

[flash.display.DisplayObject.getRect()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29)

ex: sprite1.getRect(stage).intersects(sprite2.getRect(stage));

Comment: thanks! I'm gonna go with flash.display.DisplayObject.hitTest()

Answer (score 1):

You can use hitTestObject http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29

```
trace(shape1.hitTestObject(shape2));
```

But keep in mind that this is a simplistic test if just the bounds of the objects overlap. If you want pixel-perfect collision testing you'll have to use some 3rd-party library such as http://www.freeactionscript.com/2011/08/as3-pixel-perfect-collision-detection/